# OpenVino can't install on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openvino, ubuntu-22.04

can any one help me to install OpenVino in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS each time I try to install, it giving me errors (E: Unable to locate package openvino) . I tried to installing it with Exp1: sudo apt install openvino
Exp2: sudo apt install openvino-..

Comment: This should be asked on either [su] or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) rather than here, since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

The latest OpenVINO™ 2022.1 release only supports Ubuntu 18.04 long-term support (LTS),64 bit and Ubuntu 20.04 long-term support (LTS), 64-bit.

Refer to the [Release Notes](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/openvino-relnotes.html) for new features enablement and supportabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Would your use-case allow to use OpenVINO in a Docker container? Then you could use one of the pre-built OpenVINO Docker container images.

Have a look here: https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_docker_linux.html